# How Can I install php7.1-unzip in Ubuntu server 18.04 to install Laravel5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I have this Warning.
As there is no 'unzip' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension.
This may cause invalid reports of corrupted archives. Installing 'unzip' may remediate them.
Can someone give me an explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try running

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install unzip php-zip`